# Error in VS Code when working with Git repositories

Tags: reactjs, git, github, visual-studio-code, error-handling

I'm new to git.So when I'm dealing with it I got a problem.This is the problem,

I committed 5 files from my local repository to the remote repository. But after that I wanted to change that commit message and also only to commit 3 files from previous commit. So I committed **(used undo last commit -> staged 3 files from previous 5 files -> commit)** those 3 files to the local repository. After that when I'm pushing newly committed my local repository to the remote repository I get a error message from vs code like this.

**-->>"Please clean your repository working tree before checkout"<<--**-

**This is the screenshot of error message**
[image: This is the screenshot of error message]

Also It's command output is stated like below,

**This is the command output**
[image: This is the command output]

So what should I do to fix this error? Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share the output of your terminal in a text form rather than with a screenshot?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I'm unable to put my error output in text form right now because I solved it. So I can't get that error right now. If I need to get like that I have to do this again. If I do this then I may have to undo my successful commit. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.In this I only had to **force push** my local repository to the to the remote repository. Because in this scenario I can't push my local repository in the normal way. this is the code which I typed in the command prompt,

`git push -f <remote> <branch>`

By this I pushed my local repository to the remote repository.

**Note**:-Also I found a way to **do this in vs code without typing this code in command prompt.** Just go to `File-> Preferences-> Settings-> Extensions-> Git-> Allow Force Push`. Then after that you can see in the `Source control-> Three dots` that there is a option for **Pull(Force)**. You can see a screenshot image of it.

**[image: This is option in the vs code to use Pull(Force)]**

**Thanks for everyone** who tried to find answer for this question.